# Table lock timeout when executing REST API functional test in Grails 2.4.4 using an in-memory H2 database

Tags: rest, grails, testing, locking, functional-testing

I am trying to create a set of functional test for my REST API using the [funky-spock](http://grails.org/plugin/funky-spock) and the [rest-client-builder](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) plugins.

My H2 DB connection string looks like this:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb:MVCC=true;LOCK_TIMEOUT=5000"
```

First I initialize my h2 database introducing some records in the setup() method.
And everything works fine.

```
def setup() {
    // Clean elasticsearch index
    elasticSearchService.reinitialiseIndex()

    // Initialize the DB
    // 1st question
    questionService.createQuestionFromOccurrence(
            '181718e6-fd3b-4a1b-8b40-3f83fd2965e5',
            QuestionType.IDENTIFICATION,
            ['kangaroo', 'grey'],
            userMick,
            '1st question 1st comment'
    )
}
```

But when I execute my test and perform my POST request:

```
RestResponse response = rest.post("http://localhost:8080/${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'}/ws/question") {
    json([
            source      : 'biocache',
            occurrenceId: 'f6f8a9b8-4d52-49c3-9352-155f154fc96c',
            userId      : userKeef.alaUserId,
            tags        : 'octopus, orange',
            comment     : 'whatever'
    ])
}
```

the process fails in the first DB operation which in this case is a `get()` with the following exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - JdbcSQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /taxon-overflow/ws/question
Timeout trying to lock table "QUESTION"; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all DB operations within a Grails test are performed in a transaction that is rolled back after each test. Apparently it also locks the DB and since the REST request will be executed in a separate thread to the TEST, it means it cannot access the DB. And even if it was not locked the process would not see the data as it is never committed.

One way to make this work is to make the test `not transactional' by adding the attribute to your test:

```
class RestAPISpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    static transactional = false
    ...
}
```

One of the problems with this approach is that you will have to `cleanup()` the database manually after each test. Here is the easiest way I found to do this:

```
def grailsApplication
def sessionFactory
...
def cleanup() {
    (grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain") as List).each {
        it.newInstance().list()*.delete()
    }
    sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
    sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()

    sourceService.init()
}
```

Another approach is to test your REST API by testing the controller in an integrated test which is a bit cumbersome as well and it is not really and e2e testing of your web service. On the other hand it executes a bit faster than a functional test.